# Open Virtual Directory File Using ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Problem Statement**:
As per requirement image should be opened in windows photo viewer, when button is clicked. That image is on server in a virtual directory, so that asp.net allow user to access that image file. On clicking next or previous button of windows photo viewer will show next or previous image as per default behiviour of photoviewer.

**What I Tried**:
I have wrote a program to open file in windows photo viewer. Here are the snapshots program.

When image was opened from local drive, It was opened in photo viewer

[image: When image was opened from local drive, It was opened in photo viewer]

But when virtual directory path was given to open in photo viewer, it was opened in browser.

[image: when virtual file was given to be opened]

Here is the snapshot of code

[image: Code View]

ProcessStartInfo open file in it's default program so what it did is that when it identified that its a url then it opened file in browser.

**Assumptions**:
Let's assume that image photo viewer is the default viewer for view all types of images.

**Solution Required**:
What i want is to open the virtual location files in windows photo viewer if the file is image file. Or anyone can came with better options as i have to open image file in photoviewer because i want to view image file with all options like Next, Previous, Rotate and Zoom.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think, you need to download image first and then open it

Comment: But i think that's not a good option as i have to show next and previous images in that directory too. As per your suggestion i have to download all the images.

Comment: You are getting all confused with what is on client side and what is not server side. You have created a website with an image on the server. When you start a process in ASP.NET code behind, the process runs on server. In your case, client and server are the same. But image if you deployed this application on cloud, the process will be started on cloud server and not on your client machine. What you need to do is think about what you really need to do.

Comment: well thanks decyclone. I want to start the process on client side but the file is on server side. So as per my understanding the process should access the server file. It shouldn't be an issue for client. In case of Virtual directory image what happen is that file in opened in browser so that means that the file could also be opened in photoviewer.

Comment: No, a client cannot access a file on server. It IS an issue. You can either use a LightBox library to display pictures or create Silverlight, Java, Flash plugin to download the file from server to client and open it on client or create a browser plugin to do that.

Comment: OK thanks decyclone. That means i have to change my way to implement this issue. Is there any plugin that can help me in that case the one i know is jquery.iviewer but it doestn't have full screen, Next and Previous. By the way thanks for your help